# Angular 2 Router Link with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have a route like this

```
   path: 'projects/:id/settings'
```

And in my header.component.html I want to have a link to this page

```
<a routerLink="['projects', progectId,'settings']" routerLinkActive="active">cool link</a>
```

I have a project.component, where when I click on some project I go on the project page. And then I need have a possibility go to `projects/:id/settings` or another similar route.

How can I pass `progectId` variable from projects.component?
Or maybe somebody knows another way to implement this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue for this kind of `route` you should use `routerLink` like this:

```
<a routerLink="/projects/{{progectId}}/settings" routerLinkActive="active">cool link</a>
```

and change your `route path` in `routing module` like this:

```
{ path: ':id/settings', component: YourComponent}
```

for additional information to get `projectId` you should follow these step:

1. Inject `ActivatedRoute` `object` in your `component constructor`.
2. Define a `variable` called `projectId` in your `component`.
3. Get `params` by `activatedRoute` `object` in `ngOnInit()` method.
4. Finally you should `get` `projectId` in your `html` like this: `{{projectId}}`

   ```
   import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-your-component',
     templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
   })

   export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

     private projectId: string;

     constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

     ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.projectId = params['id'];
     });
    }}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I generally do this in the component class like this

```
somefunctionName() {
    let link = ['/summary', this.param1, this.param2];
    this.router.navigate(link);
}
```

And then call the function from the html code like this

```
<a (click)="somefunctionName()">
```

In your case since I am assuming you are looping through your projects you could call your function with a parameter like this

```
<a (click)="somefunctionName(pass the parameter here)">
```

Then change the function definition to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe yo don't understand me. I know how build a link. I ask how i can get a  :id parametr from another component? Because i have it only in project.component but want have it in header.component.

Comment: Sorry about that I misunderstood your question. Can we please see how you are calling the other component in your html? Depending on this code this would be a simple case of input variable or a view child.

Comment: I'm resolve this problem, by creating a service where i save a current Project and then can use it anywhere